# How to configure the Partner Center API with MFA (App & User)?

Tags: rest, pyspark, oauth-2.0, azure-web-app-service, microsoft-partnercenter-java

I'm trying to follow the steps in this link:
https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/partner-rest/blob/docs/partner-rest/develop/api-authentication.md

But after the creation of the app and user access, it doesn't show how to call the API.
I'm trying to connect using Python/Spark, but can't go further because there's no documentation that explains how to do it step-by-step.

The code below is an example from the app-only authentication, it works but it doesn't allow to get some data that requires the app+user auth.

```
import requests, json
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.types import StructField, StringType, IntegerType, StructType

access_var = {
    "auth_url": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenantid/oauth2/token",
    "resource": "https://graph.windows.net",
    "client_id": {mssparkutils.credentials.getSecret('https://vaultname.vault.azure.net/', 'KV-Client-ID')},
    "client_st": {mssparkutils.credentials.getSecret('https://vaultname.vault.azure.net/', 'KV-Client-Secret')},
    "grant_type": "client_credentials"
}

_schema = StructType([
    StructField("Tenant ID", StringType(), True),
    StructField("Domain", StringType(), True),
    StructField("Company", StringType(), True),
    StructField("URI", StringType(), True)
])

def get_access():
    _body = {
            "resource": access_var["resource"],
            "client_id": access_var["client_id"],
            "client_secret": access_var["client_st"],
            "grant_type": access_var["grant_type"]
    }

    _headers = {"Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"}
    response = requests.post(access_var["auth_url"], data=_body, headers=_headers)
    response.raise_for_status()
    return response.json()

response = get_access()
access_t = response["access_token"]

def catch(api_url):
    "https://api.partnercenter.microsoft.com/v1/customers"

def fetch():
    api_url = "https://api.partnercenter.microsoft.com/v1/customers"
    api_auth = {
        "Authorization": f"Bearer {access_t}",
        "Accept": "application/json"
    }
    api_response = requests.get(api_url, headers=api_auth)
    return api_response.json()

def create_df(spark, result_list):
    return spark.createDataFrame(result_list, schema=_schema)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("API_CALL").getOrCreate()
    all_results = []

    data = fetch()
    result_list = data

    for item in result_list["items"]:
        tenant_id = item["companyProfile"].get("tenantId", "N/A").strip()
        domain = item["companyProfile"].get("domain", "N/A").strip()
        company_name = item["companyProfile"].get("companyName").strip()
        uri = item["links"]["self"]["uri"]

        all_results.append((tenant_id, domain, company_name, uri))
    
    df = create_df(spark, all_results)
    df.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

> You need to use **delegated** flows like authorization code or interactive flow to generate token for Partner Center API when user's MFA is enabled.

Register Azure AD application and grant `API permissions` of **Delegated** type as below:

[image]

While using interactive flow, you must include  **redirect URI** for the *Mobile and Desktop applications* platform:

[image]

Make sure to  **enable public client**  flows in your app registration like this:

[image]

Now, make use of below Python code to generate **access token** for Partner Center API using interactive flow that asks user to sign in:

```py
import msal

tenant_id = "tenantId"
client_id = "appId"
authority = f'https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant_id}'

scope = ["https://api.partnercenter.microsoft.com/user_impersonation"]

app = msal.PublicClientApplication(
    client_id,
    authority=authority,
)

token_response = app.acquire_token_interactive(scopes=scope)
access_token = token_response['access_token']
print("Access token:", access_token)
```

**Response:**

[image]

You can decode the above token in [jwt.ms](https://jwt.ms) and check whether **`aud`** & **`scp`** claims have **valid** values or not:

[image]

Using the above token, you can make requests to **Partner Center API** with below updated python code:

```py
import msal

tenant_id = "tenantId"
client_id = "appId"
authority = f'https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant_id}'

scope = "https://api.partnercenter.microsoft.com/user_impersonation"

app = msal.PublicClientApplication(
    client_id,
    authority=authority,
)

token_response = app.acquire_token_interactive(scopes=scope)
access_token = token_response['access_token']

# Make a request to the Partner Center API
api_url = "https://api.partnercenter.microsoft.com/v1/customers"
headers = {
    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + access_token,
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
}

response = requests.get(api_url, headers=headers)

if response.status_code == 200:
    print("API request successful")
    print(response.json())
else:
    print(f"API request failed with status code {response.status_code}")
    print(response.text)
```

**Reference:**
[Partner Center authentication - Partner app developer | Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/partner-center/developer/partner-center-authentication#app--user-authentication)